# Asynchronous promise handling with Bluebird

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, bluebird

For some reasons, I get a Bluebird promise to which I attach handlers asynchronously. For example:

```
var promise = Promise.reject(new Error('Handled rejection'));

setImmediate(function () {
    promise.then(console.log, console.error);
});
```

Although my promise is well handled, Bluebird warns me about an unhandled rejection.

I can fool it by synchronously adding an empty rejection handler:

```
promise.catch(function () {});
```

However, this looks really hacky. Is there any proper way to handle this kind of situation?

**EDIT**: in answer to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31028743/asynchronous-promise-handling-with-bluebird#comment50108012_31030749), I posted a more detailed illustration of my real use case in [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/connesc/10d54fcba54e3dbaf2c3). It also contains the workaround that I use while waiting the release of Bluebird 3.0. As Benjamin explained, Bluebird 3.0 will bring a solution with `.suppressUnhandledRejection()`.

Comment: Why do you need to wrap this code in a `setImmediate`? `.then` should already cause the `.then` handlers to run asynchronously.

Comment: This code is just for illustrative purposes. In my real application, the callback is not registered in a `setImmediate` but in a true asynchronous process (see [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31028743/asynchronous-promise-handling-with-bluebird/31029262#comment50085244_31029262) for details).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [global rejection events](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#global-rejection-events), specifically `unhandledRejection`, to silently consume the possibly unhandled rejection.  However, this means that real unhandled rejections will also be silenced.

You can use `rejectionHandled` in conjunction with `unhandledRejection` to make your own decision about whether a rejection was handled or not.

Alternatively, you can be very careful about calling `done` at the end of every promise chain, in which case you can safely ignore the possibly unhandled rejections.

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer! However, I was looking for a way to handle this situation locally, without altering the global detection of unhandled rejections.

Comment: @connesc Do you have to attach the handler asynchronously?  You could wait to start the promise until you're ready to attach the handler.  Otherwise I don't think it is possible, because of the way Bluebird detects unhandled rejections.

Comment: Yes, I really need to attach the handler asynchronously. I cannot defer the promise creation because it is built on top of an event emitter (otherwise, I may miss some events). I will consider refactoring my code in order to avoid such a situation. However, it is a bit frustrating to workaround false positives. Anyway, thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

> However, this looks really hacky. Is there any proper way to handle this kind of situation?

In 3.0 we have `.suppressUnhandledRejection()`. In 2.0 that's as far as you go. In my experience the situations where you actually need to attach handlers asynchronously are extremely rare and my first instinct is to suspect a problem with the code structure.

In either case, Aaron's answer already explains how to use the global rejection events which have the benefit of spanning across instances of bluebird and even other libraries throughout the code.

Comment: `.suppressUnhandledRejection()` will be perfect for me, thanks for the information. I agree that my use case is uncommon, but it is actually not a design issue (I may post a more elaborate code sample to illustrate this if you wish). I believe that a promise library must remain as general-purpose as possible. Assumptions about common usages are crucial to provide an efficient API, but it is even better if they don't lead to unnecessary restrictions. Since a promise basically wraps the result of an asynchronous job, I should be able to launch the job, and then care about the result later.

Comment: @connesc I will choose pragmatism over theoretical correctness any day. In every case of real code I've seen yet, unhandled rejection either uncovered a suppressed exception or a race condition in the design. That said, for the same pragmatism you can also opt out of the whole mechanism or a single rejection, and for it you have an explicit opt out command in 3.0. It's entirely possible that your use case is justified but I've dealt a lot with promises and I've yet to see one. If you feel like it (no pressure) and want to share the actual use case - please do.

Comment: Yes, being able to opt out the mechanism is the key feature for me (and it will be even better in 3.0). I tried to extract the essence of my use case, and I posted it in [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/connesc/10d54fcba54e3dbaf2c3). I also added the workaround that I use for now. I am really interested in your opinion about both.